# Can decision tree learning be "semi-supervised"

Tags: machine-learning, tree, decision-tree, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a dataset that includes three types of variables: states of nature, human decisions, response variable. I'm trying to predict the response variable using the other variables using decision tree learning.

My mental model is that people are looking at the states of nature and making decisions. Hence, I strongly prefer to have my decision trees start by partitioning according to the state of nature variables, and subsequently partition based on the human decision variables. I would prefer not to just chuck all the variables in a decision tree model and see what pops out.

Is that mental model valid and if so how would I implement something like this using, say, Azure ML? I don't even know the right words to describe this problem - is this "semi-supervised" decision tree learning?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "semi-supervised" part here. semi-supervised means that part of the data lacks labels (response variables), which is not the case. you simply propose quite odd constraint for the decision tree learning, to process subset of features in the end. In order to do something like this you will need to change the DT learning procedure, or preferably - code it from scratch. DT is extremely simple algorithm, which takes few hundreads lines of code, and your modification is a simple if inside, which says "if, on the path from the root we are not using yet all the meaningful 'nature' features, do not look into 'human decisions'". Thus it is pretty straightforwad, but I do not think any library actually supports this kind of constraint (as it is far from natural, especially for DT).